# php - check if $_POST is array?

Tags: php, arrays, global

I know this may be a silly question, but I come across a snippet of php code that check if the `$_POST` `is_array()` before execute other functions.

Now I guess that $_POST should be always an associative array or not? is this check really needed? and why?

Comment: Not always. I'm personally using an object wrapper around $_POST, $_GET and Co. They work as array still, but are ArrayObjects and would fail that simple `is_array()` check. But that's an awfully special case. Not usually a concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it hasn't been changed in some manner like

```
$_POST = 'not array';
```

then it is array ;-)

Comment: Exactly. Unless otherwise explicitly declared the $_POST superglobal is always an array.

Comment: ok, but, it can be changed only by the coder or it can be setted to string also by form submitters? can this be a security issue?

Comment: @Julie Rokk: if it hasn't been changed **explicitly by a developer** as I answered - it is **always an array**. It is not possible to change it outside.

Answer (score 3):

$_POST is always an array, they're probably checking if a certain $_POST value is an array.

`<input name="test" />` $_POST['test'] is not an array

`<input name="test[]" />` $_POST['test'] **is** an array

Answer (score 3):

- **$_POST** is a superglobal and is **always defined** (always exists) and is always an array
- this is true, even if it doesn't contain any elements
- it is possible though, if not advisable and I've never seen it, to overwrite or unset it
- you don't need isset() and is_array() for the $_POST array but you will quite often need them for elements in the $_POST array

Comment: thank's for your responce, i want to up-vote your answer, cause it is detailed, although i feel to check the zerkms one, cause it said what i was looking for; i already knew all the other details.

Answer (score 2):

That check is unnecessary.  $_POST is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array which is always defined.  You should just check for specific elements using `isset`

Answer (score 1):

PHP makes sure that $_POST is always an array, you don't need to do that check unless somewhere in your code you either unset or overwrite $_POST somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Its always an array as many already gave said.

I think the intention is maybe to check for an empty array. !empty($_POST) should do just fine.

Maybe the coder has sections where the array is changed to a string (dumb if you ask me) and wants to make the check, else if that statement comes first, then its unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is always defined as an array even it doesn't contain any key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned several times, `$_POST` is a superglobal that is always defined and always an array (unless overwritten).

If you're attempting to test if something has been posted, you could use something like follows:

```
if (count($_POST)) {
    // something has been submitted
}
```

To answer the main question, no, the `is_array` check is not required.