# Checking if form has been submitted - PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation

What is the best way of checking whether or not a form has been submitted to determine whether I should pass the form's variables to my validation class?

First I thought maybe:

```
isset($_POST)
```

But that will always return true as a superglobal is defined everywhere. I don't want to have to iterate through each element of my form with:

```
if(isset($_POST['element1']) || isset($_POST['element2']) || isset(...etc
```

Whilst writing this question I thought of a much more basic solution, add a hidden field to act as a flag that I can check.

**Is there a 'cleaner' way to do it than adding my own flag?**

Comment: Well, you could make a submit button that has a specific nam, like `submited` and then use the php `if(isset($_POST['submited']))` or a hidden input...

Comment: You should add a nounce to prevent replay attacks on your form.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

For general check if there was a `POST` action use:

```
if ($_POST)
```

**EDIT**: As stated in the comments, this method won't work for in some cases (e.g. with check boxes and button without a name). You really should use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score 183):

How about

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score 75):

Actually, the submit button already performs this function.

Try in the FORM:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="treasure" value="go!">
</form>
```

Then in the PHP handler:

```
if (isset($_POST['treasure'])){
echo "treasure will be set if the form has been submitted (to TRUE, I believe)";
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Simply checking for $_POST isn't good enough because it could've been generated from a number of different places...not just from a form post. Thanks Tzshand.

Comment: Ideally now you should use `if (null !== (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'macaddress'))){` which gets you in the habit of using filter_input

Comment: POST can be done with Ajax, which won't have any submit button, so this is not a universal solution.

Comment: That's true; it can also check any variable posted by AJAX.

Answer (score 38):

Use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // name of your submit button
```

Comment: But some forms may have multiple buttons.

Comment: @rilwis sometimes forms are submitted by JavaScript and don't need/have a submit button

Answer (score 30):

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
 <form action="" method="POST" id="formaddtask">
      Add Task: <input type="text"name="newtaskname" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>

    //Check if the form is submitted
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['newtaskname'])){

    }
```

Comment: This method is the most recommended, since it seems to be recognized as "best practice" by the "coding academy".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - also make sure you add `name=""` in the input button. Well, that fix worked for me.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['add'])){
    echo "stuff is happening now";
}

<input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

On a different note, it is also always a good practice to add a token to your form and verify it to check if the data was not sent from outside.  Here are the steps:

1. Generate a unique token (you can use hash) Ex:

   ```
   $token = hash (string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] );
   ```
2. Assign this token to a session variable. Ex:

   ```
   $_SESSION['form_token'] = $token;
   ```
3. Add a hidden input to submit the token. Ex:

   ```
   input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$token}"
   ```
4. then as part of your validation, check if the submitted token
   matches the session var.

   ```
   Ex: if ( $_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['form_token'] ) ....
   ```

Comment: this only works if the user doesn't inspect the element and sniff the value to run in their bots

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

**It is assumed and highly recommended to handle form in POST method instead of GET.**

It is recommended to keep the form handler and form HTML page different and redirect to the HTML page from the handler, so the user doesn't submit the form twice.

Add a token to the form to prevent spam.

Answer (score -6):

You could also use:

```
is_array($_POST)
```

Comment: `is_array($_POST)` always gives true (on my machine). According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594020/php-check-if-post-is-array: `$_POST is a superglobal array which is always defined` , `unless somewhere in your code you either unset or overwrite $_POST somehow`, so it seems to be expected that this always returns true..

Comment: `is_array($_POST)` is definitely not the way to check if the form was submitted.