# Right method to check if user submitted a form

Tags: php, forms, post, get, form-submit

I have a page with a form. Which of the following methods is the best to use to check if the form is submitted? And how are they different?

Method 1:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //some code
}
```

Method 2:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //some code
}
```

Method 3 (obviously if I add `submitted=true` on submit to the query string):

```
if($_GET['submitted'] == true){
    //some code
}
```

Comment: `$_GET[]` gives you all submitted information into the url. `$_POST[]` gives you all submitted information without displaying in url. `$_REQUEST` handle both `GET` and `POST`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if form has been submitted - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711466/checking-if-form-has-been-submitted-php)

Comment: Nothing to do with Jquery... I use Method 2. if FORM submitted via POST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method 1 and method 2 are the most appropriate ones.

If you validate the form using a `$_GET['submitted'] == true` this could easily be cracked by the end user which creates a security breach.

The best method i think is the first one

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

This piece of code works good even on dynamically generated forms wherein you do not have to check a post variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *post* a form, then you should **always** use the appropriate HTTP request, `POST`. Furthermore, in most cases, it probably makes sense to check explicitly for a posted key, as you may have multiple forms on your page. Here's a break down of your methods. The second approach seems the best.:

---

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Check the see if the request method was of type `POST`. Not checking for data of any specific type.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Check to see if the key `submit` has been *posted* to the server.

```
if($_GET['submitted'] == true)
```

Check to see if the *get parameter* `submitted`, assumed to be set, is equal to `true`

---

See [the difference between GET and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) for more. Specifically when it comes to posting forms, you should be aware of [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 0):

In general if POST action then simply use

```
if (!empty($_POST))
```