# Tough one... I'm getting undefined index errors

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, undefined-index

I'm working on this project and the goal is to have these forms search a database and pull the data out in a table like format. When I try to load this I'm getting undefined index errors...

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ValidarDatos.js"></script>


<title></title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="content">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="#"> <img src="images/logo.jpg" /></a> </div>
    <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="ConsultaNino.php" class="seleccionado">Niños</a></li>
            <li><a href="ConsultaPadrino.php">Padrinos</a></li>
            <li><a href="ConsultaCentro.php">Centros</a></li>
            <li><a href="Informes.php">Informes</a></li>            
            <li><a href="ConsultaUsuario.php">Usuarios</a></li>         
            <li><a href="Security/aut_logout.php">Salir</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="intro2">
        <h1>Intranet Coprodeli</h1>
        <p>Apadrinamiento y Programa<br />
            de Niños en Alto Riesgo</p>
        <div id="login">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right2">
    <h4 class="migas">Estás en: <a href="home.php">Inicio</a> | Consulta de niños</h4>
    <br />

    <fieldset class="required">
        <legend>Consulta de niños:</legend>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="consultanino.php">
          <p>
            <label for="ninoid">ID niño:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ninoid" id="ninoid" />
</p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
  <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />
          </p>
          <p>          <br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" />
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" />
            <label for="sexo">Sexo:</label>
            <select name="sexo" id="sexo">
              <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
              <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
            <select name="estado" id="estado">
              <option value="Asignable">Asignable</option>
              <option value="Asignado">Asignado</option>
              <option value="Pendiente de Estado">Pendiente de Estado</option>
              <option value="Baja  Solicitado">Baja  Solicitado</option>
              <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" />
            <label for="fecha_de_nacimiento_desde">Fecha de <br />
              nacimiento desde <br />
              (DD-MM-YYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" name="fecha_de_nacimiento_desde" id="fecha_de_nacimiento_desde" />
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><br class="clear" />
            <label for="fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta">Fecha de<br />
              nacimiento hasta<br />
              (DD-MM-YYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" name="fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta" id="fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta" />
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="tipo_de_centro">Tipo de centro:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_de_centro[]" value="CAE" id="tipo_de_centro_0" />CAE
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_de_centro[]" value="CE" id="tipo_de_centro_1" />CE
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_de_centro[]" value="CH" id="tipo_de_centro_2" />CH
          <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_de_centro[]" value="SEGUIMIENTO" id="tipo_de_centro_3" />SEGUIMIENTO          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" />
            <label for="nombre_del_centro">Nombre Del Centro: :</label>      
            <select name="nombre_del_centro" id="nombre_del_centro">
              <option value="CAE GAMBETTA">CAE GAMBETTA</option>
              <option value="CAE SAN JUAN MACIAS">CAE SAN JUAN MACIAS</option>
              <option value="CAE SAN MARTIN">CAE SAN MARTIN</option>
              <option value="CAE SAN VICENTE (BOLOGNESI)">CAE SAN VICENTE (BOLOGNESI)</option>
              <option value="CAE SANTO DOMINGO SAVIO">CAE SANTO DOMINGO SAVIO</option>
              <option value="CES SAN FRANCISCO SOLANO">CES SAN FRANCISCO SOLANO</option>
              <option value="CES SAN JUAN MACIAS">CES SAN JUAN MACIAS</option>
              <option value="CES SAN MARTIN">CES SAN MARTIN</option>
              <option value="CES SAN MIGUEL">CES SAN MIGUEL</option>
              <option value="CES SAN VICENTE">CES SAN VICENTE</option>
              <option value="MARIA ANA MOGASCH NUESTRA SEÑORA DEL MAR">MARIA ANA MOGASCH NUESTRA SEÑORA DEL MAR</option>
              <option value="CAE SAN ANTONIO (ICA)">CAE SAN ANTONIO (ICA)</option>
              <option value="CES SAN ANTONIO (ICA)">CES SAN ANTONIO (ICA)</option>
              <option value="CAE STA. MARIA (PACHACUTEC)">CAE STA. MARIA (PACHACUTEC)</option>
              <option value="CES STA. MARIA (PACHACUTEC)">CES STA. MARIA (PACHACUTEC)</option>
              <option value="CAE SAN PEDRO (CHINCHA - ICA)">CAE SAN PEDRO (CHINCHA - ICA)</option>
              <option value="CES SAN PEDRO (CHINCHA - ICA)">CES SAN PEDRO (CHINCHA - ICA)</option>
              <option value="CES SAN LUIS (CAÑETE - ICA)">CES SAN LUIS (CAÑETE - ICA)</option>
              <option value="CAE NUESTRA SRA. DE LAS AMERICAS (PISCO - ICA)">CAE NUESTRA SRA. DE LAS AMERICAS (PISCO - ICA)</option>
              <option value="CES NUESTRA SRA. DE LAS AMERICAS (PISCO - ICA)">CES NUESTRA SRA. DE LAS AMERICAS (PISCO - ICA)</option>
              <option value="CES SAN AGUSTIN DE HIPONA">CES SAN AGUSTIN DE HIPONA</option>
              <option value="CAE BOLOGNESI">CAE BOLOGNESI</option>
              <option value="CES NAZCA">CES NAZCA</option>
              <option value="CES CORPUS CRISTI (Pablos esto es el CES NAZCA)">CES CORPUS CRISTI (Pablos esto es el CES NAZCA)</option>
              <option value="CES CRISTO SACERDOTE - LURIN">CES CRISTO SACERDOTE - LURIN</option>
              <option value="CAE SAN JUDAS TADEO">CAE SAN JUDAS TADEO</option>
              <option value="CAE BETANIA">CAE BETANIA</option>
              <option value="SEGUIMIENTO CAE">SEGUIMIENTO CAE</option>
              <option value="SEGUIMIENTO CES">SEGUIMIENTO CES</option>
              <option value="SEGUIMIENTO HOGARES">SEGUIMIENTO HOGARES</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="region_del_centro">Región del Centro:</label>
            <select name="region_del_centro" id="region_del_centro">
              <option value="Pachacutec, Peru">Pachacutec, Peru</option>
              <option value="Callao, Peru">Callao, Peru</option>
              <option value="Ica, Peru">Ica, Peru</option>
              <option value="San Martin, Peru">San Martin, Peru</option>
            </select>
          </p>

          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="nivel_de_estudio">Nivel de estudio:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nivel_de_estudio" id="nivel_de_estudio" />
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="entrada_desde">Entrada desde <br />
            (DD-MM-YYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" name="entrada_desde" id="entrada_desde" />
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="entrada_hasta">Entrada hasta <br />
            (DD-MM-YYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" name="entrada_hasta" id="entrada_hasta" />
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="egreso_desde">Egreso desde <br />
            (DD-MM-YYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" name="egreso_desde" id="egreso_desde" />
          </p>
          <p><br class="clear" /> 
            <label for="egreso_hasta">Egreso hasta <br />
            (DD-MM-YYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" name="egreso_hasta" id="egreso_hasta" />
            <br class="clear" />
          </p> 
      </form>
      <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
          <input  type="text" name="name"> 
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
    </form> 





      </fieldset>



        <fieldset id="" class="required">
        <legend>Resultado de la b&uacute;squeda:</legend>
        <form id="form7" name="ResultadoBusqueda" action="ConsultarDetalleNino.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="especial" width="11"></td>
            <td colspan="6" class="especial"> </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th width="15"></th>
                    <th width="88">Estado</th>
                    <th width="104">ID ni&ntilde;o </th>
                    <th width="234">Apellidos</th>
                    <th width="81">Nombre</th>
                    <th width="128">Fecha Ingreso</th>
                    <th width="106">Fecha Egreso</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
  <?php          
            $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<tr>";
while ($header = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<td>". $header['Field']."</td>";
}
echo "<br>\n";
echo "</tr>";

$ninoid = $_POST['ninoid'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$fecha_de_nacimiento_desde = $_POST['fecha_de_nacimiento_desde'];
$fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta = $_POST['fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta'];
$tipo_de_centro = $_POST['tipo_de_centro'];
$nombre_del_centro = $_POST['nombre_del_centro'];
$region_del_centro = $_POST['region_del_centro'];
$nivel_de_estudio = $_POST['nivel_de_estudio'];
$entrada_desde = $_POST['entrada_desde'];
$entrada_hasta = $_POST['entrada_hasta'];
$egreso_desde = $_POST['egreso_desde'];
$egreso_hasta = $_POST['egreso_hasta'];
$padrino_nombre = $_POST['padrino_nombre'];
$query = "select ninoid, nombre, apellidos, sexo, fecha_de_nacimiento_desde, 
fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta, tipo_de_centro, nombre_del_centro, region_del_centro, entrada_desde, 
entrada_hasta, egreso_desde, egreso_hasta, p.padrino_nombre FROM nino INNER JOIN padrino p ON nino.padrino_nombre = p.padrino_nombre WHERE ninoid = '$ninoid' AND nombre = '$nombre' 
AND apellidos = '$apellidos' AND sexo = '$sexo' AND estado = '$estado' AND fecha_de_nacimiento_desde = 
'$fecha_de_nacimiento_desde' AND fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta = '$fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta' 
AND tipo_de_centro = '$tipo_de_centro' AND nombre_del_centro = '$nombre_del_centro' 
AND region_del_centro = '$region_del_centro' AND nivel_de_estudio = '$nivel_de_estudio' AND entrada_desde = '$entrada_desde' 
AND entrada_hasta = '$entrada_hasta' AND egreso_desde = '$egreso_desde' 
AND egreso_hasta = '$egreso_hasta' AND p.padrino_nombre = '$padrino_nombre'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>".$line['estado']."</d>";
    echo "<td>".$line['ninoid']."</d>";
    echo "<td>".$line['apellidos']."</d>";
    echo "<td>".$line['nombre']."</d>";
    echo "<td>".$line['egreso_desde']."</d>";
    echo "<td>".$line['centro']."</d>";
    echo "<td>".$line['padrino_nombre']."</d>";
    echo "<br>\n";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>            
        <div class="actions">
        <input name="ConsultarDetalleNino" type="submit" class="primaryAction" id="submit-" value="Consultar Detalle">



            <input name="Cancelar" type="submit" class="primaryAction" id="submit-" value="Cancelar">
        </div>

        </form>
        <form id="ListadoNinos" name="ListadoNinos" action="InformeNinos.php"  method="post" target="_blank"></form>
        </fieldset>

    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="col1">
        <p><a href="#"> </a><a href="#"></a><br />
            &copy;  <a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <p>Info:<strong><a href=""></a></strong><br />
            Info2: <strong>completar</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here are the errors where the indexes are located:

```
 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 210
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0
2   0.0174  333248  mysql_fetch_array ( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:210


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: ninoid in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 216
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: nombre in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 217
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: apellidos in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 218
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: sexo in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 219
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: estado in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 220
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fecha_de_nacimiento_desde in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 221
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 222
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: tipo_de_centro in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 223
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: nombre_del_centro in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 224
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: region_del_centro in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 225
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: nivel_de_estudio in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 226
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: entrada_desde in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 227
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: entrada_hasta in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 228
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: egreso_desde in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 229
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: egreso_hasta in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 230
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: padrino_nombre in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 231
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  268976  {main}( )   ..\ConsultaNino.php:0

( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 242
```

Comment: so we have to go over your entire code to determine "which" one(s) is undefined.. *lovely*.

Comment: it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index *am sure*.

Comment: If you guys look at the Original post I have included the errors. Sorry about that.

Comment: Don't try to use `$_POST` unless a POST is submitted. `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in J:\wamp\www\ConsultaNino.php on line 210
Call Stack` your query is failing for some reason, check the errors. This code is open to SQL injections. You also should switch drivers, PDO or MYSQLi.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the insight. Instead of a post what should I be using? Also I'm like SUPER-new to PHP and I've been following tutorials on youtube but unfortunately they're outdated regarding this so I used the normal php. That does scare me though, how would I switch drivers from pdo or mysqli then? Also will this affect my code that I have here? So what should I do instead of using POST?

Comment: Not instead of POST, but check if a POST has been submitted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711466/checking-if-form-has-been-submitted-php The PDO or MYSQLi is your choice, I went with PDO because I first had to use mssql. Here's a thread on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons and for SQL injection prevention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your errors do not line up with the code you submitted.  For example, if "mysql_fetch_array" is on line 210, then "ninoid" is in line 214, not 216.

I also noticed that you are trying to fetch "estado" when you did not select it.

Comment: This shouldn't really be posted as an answer to this question. I know you don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so you may think posting an answer is the best option, but posting non-answers to questions unfortunately isn't going to help you earn the reputation to leave comments.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this isn't the answer. Perhaps the formatting differed when I pasted it onto stackoverflow, hence why ninoid is on line 214 and not 216. Do you have anymore insight as to why this is happening?