# Hiding results if form hasnt been submitted

Tags: php

Is there a way I can hide my `IF/ELSE` results unless the form has been submitted? At the moment when i visit the pge it auto outputs the else statement.

Here is my php:

```
$height =  $_POST['height']  / 100;
$weight = $_POST['weight'];

$bmi = $weight / $height;
$bmi = $bmi / $height;

$total = 
$_POST['Radios'] +
$_POST['Radios1'] +
$_POST['Radios3'] +
$_POST['Radios4'] +
$_POST['Radios5'] +
$_POST['Radios6'];


if($total >= 2 || $bmi > 22){
    $warning = 'Your ill';
} else {
    $safe = 'Your ok';
}
```

The php is above the html form I am unable to move it to another file(restricted).

Comment: What's your `submit` input element looks like?

Comment: im just using a button `<button>Submit</button>`

Comment: it's better to separate form processing code from form html code

Comment: So why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe look at this question: ['Checking if form has been submitted'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711466/checking-if-form-has-been-submitted-php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put it on

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 // YOUR CODES GOES HERE 
}
?>
```

Put this code the page you are submitting the form. So what is does if the http request is POST then it will run the code inside of it.

Hope the helps

Comment: The just the ticket! I wrapped it all in that and it seems to be working!