# Why isset function doesn't update my database?

Tags: php, isset

I don't understand why isset function doesn't work here:

```
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$name = $_POST['title'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $insert = mysqli_query($con,
    "INSERT INTO `items`(
    `title`, 
    `text`, 
    `category`
    ) 
    VALUES (
    '$name', 
    '$text', 
    '$category')"
    );
    if (!$insert) {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    } else {
        echo "Inserted!";
    }
}




<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter the title..">
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter the text..">
<input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Enter the category..">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The database is not updated.
Without that,my code is ok,but it's not what I want.

Comment: Add the `name` attribute to submit button. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752226/4471134)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input submit has no name property

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to use the name attribut and the text of name attribut should match with isset($_POST['submit'])