# Undefined array in php

Tags: php, undefined

[image: Here is the screenshot of error which I'm getting]

Form code

```
<form action=<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="POST" id="form1">
Enter length of password:<input type="text" name="length">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

PHP code

```
    <?php 
    $length=$_POST['length']
    ?>
```

Error:

> Undefined array key "length" in D:\XWAMP\htdocs\pg\index2.php on line 30

I'm writing both html and php in single file that's why it's happening but how to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the web page loads and you get the error. In this case, you haven't check whether the form is submitted. Before the form is submitted you also haven't added a name for your submit button.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $length = $_POST['length'];
}
```

This should solve your problem I suppose. A similar question was asked here:
[Check if form was submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711466/checking-if-form-has-been-submitted-php)

Comment: Right idea, but $_POST['submit'] won't be set in this case, because the button in the OP's form has no name

Comment: I think you forgot "))" in the first line

Comment: @ADyson you're right.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé lol thanks man.

Comment: why not simply if(isset($_POST['length'])){ ...

Comment: Well then you'd have to do that if for every attribute you have say name, username, password, phone number and who knows what else you might have. The code then becomes really messy in my opinion.

Comment: you're right...

Answer (score 0):

Various issues,

- `action=<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` is open to XSS don't use it
- To check if its POST request, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`
- Always validate user input and respond in kind to the user

```
<?php
$errors = [];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   // validate length
   if (!isset($_POST['length'])) {
     $errors['length'] = 'Length is a required field';
   } else if (!is_numeric($_POST['length'])) {
     $errors['length'] = 'Length should be a number';
   } else if ($_POST['length'] < 1) {
     $errors['length'] = 'Length should be a >= then 1';
   } else if ($_POST['length'] > 1000) {
     $errors['length'] = 'Length should be a <= then 1000';
   }

   // no errors, do processing on length
   if (empty($errors)) {
      $length = $_POST['length'];

      // do something with $length
   }
} 
?>

<form action="" method="POST" id="form1">
  Enter length of password: 
  <input type="text" value="<?= isset($_POST['length']) ? htmlentities($_POST['length']) : '' ?>" name="length" required>
  <?= isset($errors['length']) ? '<div class="input-error">'.$errors['length'].'</div>' : '' ?>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```